# Convert a raw data to json using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am having input data as below, I need to phrase it to be a JSON. Working on a legacy node and don't have `jq`(mentioning in advance)

```
e1
status: up
temp: 140
alarm: none
e2
status: down
temp: 141
alarm: none
e3
status: up
temp: 144
alarm: 2
e4
status: up
temp: 65
alarm: 2
region: us-east
```

I was hoping to get the following output:

```
{"e1" : { "status": "up", "temp": "140", "alarm": "none"}}
{"e2" : { "status": "down", "temp": "141", "alarm": "none"}}
{"e3" : { "status": "up", "temp": "144", "alarm": "2"}}
{"e4" : { "status": "up", "temp": "65", "alarm": "2", "region": "us-east"}}
```

I tried to make a workaround using `awk` but not able to combine the results by key:

```
awk '!/:/{node=$0} /:/{print "{\"",node,"\"}",":", "{", $0 ,"}"  }' inputfile
{" e1 "} : { status: up }
{" e1 "} : { temp: 140 }
{" e1 "} : { alarm: none }
{" e3 "} : { status: down }
{" e3 "} : { temp: 141 }
{" e3 "} : { alarm: none }
{" e3 "} : { status: up }
{" e3 "} : { temp: 144 }
{" e3 "} : { alarm: 2 }
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: does each 'block' always consist of 4 lines? if not, please update the sample input to show blocks with different numbers of lines

Comment: @markp-fuso no, there is no guarantee that the number of lines will be fixed in each block, added the 4th bock as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One `awk` idea where we append consecutive input lines together (via the `awk/out` variable):

```
awk -F':' '                                           # input field delimiter is ":"
NF==1 { if (out)                                      # if number of ":" delimited fields is 1 then we are starting a new block, and if "out" is non-empty then ...
           print out "}}"                             # print the previous block to stdout and ...
        out="{\"" $1 "\" : { "                        # start building a new "out"
        sep=""
        next
      }
      { gsub(/^[ ]+/,"",$2)                           # strip leading spaces from 2nd field
        out=out sep "\"" $1 "\": \"" $2 "\""
        sep=", "
      }
END   { if (out)                                      # if non-empty then ...
           print out "}}"                             # flush last "out" to stdout
      }
' inputfile
```

This generates:

```
{"e1" : { "status": "up", "temp": "140", "alarm": "none"}}
{"e2" : { "status": "down", "temp": "141", "alarm": "none"}}
{"e3" : { "status": "up", "temp": "144", "alarm": "2"}}
{"e4" : { "status": "up", "temp": "65", "alarm": "2", "region": "us-east"}}
```

Answer (score 4):

[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) can do this:

```bash
jq --raw-input '
  reduce ((., inputs) | scan("([^:]+)(: (.*))?")) as $m ({obj: {}, key: null};
    if $m[1] == null
      then .key = $m[0] | .obj[.key] = {}
      else .obj[.key] += {($m[0]): $m[2]}
    end
  )
  | .obj
' inputfile
```

```json
{
  "e1": {
    "status": "up",
    "temp": "140",
    "alarm": "none"
  },
  "e2": {
    "status": "down",
    "temp": "141",
    "alarm": "none"
  },
  "e3": {
    "status": "up",
    "temp": "144",
    "alarm": "2"
  },
  "e4": {
    "status": "up",
    "temp": "65",
    "alarm": "2",
    "region": "us-east"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk approach exploiting the files text file record structure
of lines with a single field for record identifier and pairs of fields for record key-values

```
cat script.awk 
#! /usr/bin/gawk -f

NR==1 { # deal with the initial case where there is no output
    rec_id = $1; 
    next    
}
NF>1 {
    gsub(":$", "\": \"", $1);    # fix between key and value
    rec = rec " \"" $1 $2 "\","; # accumulate key-values
}
NF==1 {  # new identifier triggers printing last record
    print "{\"" id "\" : { " substr(rec,1,length(rec)-1) " }}"
    rec = ""
    rec_id = $1
}
END { # get final case out
    print "{\"" rec_id "\" : { " substr(rec,1,length(rec)-1) " }}"
}
```

Run

```
$ ./script.awk file.input 
{"e1" : {  "status": "up", "temp": "140", "alarm": "none" }}
{"e2" : {  "status": "down", "temp": "141", "alarm": "none" }}
{"e3" : {  "status": "up", "temp": "144", "alarm": "2" }}
{"e4" : {  "status": "up", "temp": "65", "alarm": "2", "region": "us-east" }}
```